# How can I add sites for SubDownloader or SMPlayer to search in?

Tags: video-player

I am new in Linux. I have installed Ubuntu with WUBI three days before and I have not opened my Windows all these days. The only thing I miss is the ability of BS.Player to find subtitles.

I have tried to install BS.Player with Wine, but it doesn't work. I have downloaded SMPlayer and SubDownloader but they cannot find subtitles in my language (Greek). In SMPlayer it says it searches on opensubtitles.org.

*How can I add some more sites in which it can search, like BS.Player did?*

Please help me, I don't want to use Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's hard coded in the source of smplayer. You'd have to manually add code to get new APIs into it. You can easily switch the server used, in src/findsubtitleswindow.cpp, but you'll have to write the API code too. I'm interested in this too, and am working on this myself.